# How to insert a sheet to Google spreadsheet in a specified location using java

Tags: java, eclipse, google-sheets-api

Am inserting a worksheet to Google spreadsheet every week with the help of following command

```
WorksheetEntry worksheet = new WorksheetEntry();
worksheet.setTitle(new PlainTextConstruct(sheet_name));
worksheet.setColCount(data[0].length);
worksheet.setRowCount(data.length);

URL worksheetFeedUrl = entry.getWorksheetFeedUrl();
service.insert(worksheetFeedUrl, worksheet);
```

Always its inserting the sheet at last position but i want to insert it at the second position every time....

Is it possible using java? If so please help me...

Thanks in advance...

Answer (score 0):

It is possible with google-apps-script, but not with the spreadsheet API (GData).

### insertSheet(sheetIndex)

[https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/spreadsheet#insertSheet(Integer)](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/spreadsheet#insertSheet%28Integer%29)
Inserts a new sheet in the spreadsheet at the given index. As a side effect, it makes it the active sheet.

```
var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
ss.insertSheet(1);
```

AFAIK, there is no such function with the spreadsheet API (GData). It is not listed here https://developers.google.com/google-apps/spreadsheets/

Comment: Thanks man... I knew its possible in apps script but i want to do it with GData....